# Effective solution to store and manage useful links

Tags: web-apps, note-taking, information-management, bookmark, hosted

Most of the time when I'm studying and coding in front of my laptop, I come across some very useful articles on the web. For example:

> Today when searching for the mechanism of arrayfun function for my
>   MATLAB code, I got curious about the difference between parallel
>   computing on multi core CPUs and GPU computing. And because I'm not a
>   professional computer expert, most of the articles on the web baffled
>   me more, so I started to search for an easy to understand definition
>   and finally, I came across [this interesting article](https://www.quora.com/How-would-you-explain-the-difference-between-a-CPU-and-a-GPU-to-a-5-year-old)

I know that there are ways like "managing bookmarks effectively on your browser" or "Google bookmarks" but I'm searching for something that has the following features at least.

- Links will be stored by their title for the ease of search and for a better view.
- It is a multi-platform tool and supports cloud storing, so problems like reinstalling the browser, etc. won't affect it.
- **Every link should be stored with its date and I also should be able to add as much tags as I like to the link when I'm storing it (this way I can easily find links belonged to a specific subject ordered by the date. Or after a few years, I can easily access the links that I encountered during my master studies because of being able to search for a specific date or period).**
- Working with it should be very easy and as fast as possible.
- I should be able to add note (without limitation in the number of character) whenever it's necessary. Meaning that I should be able to add my thoughts at the moment.
- There should not be any limitation in the number of links (because I'm going to use it for years).
- There should be some ways to back up your links or transfer them to another link management service when it's necessary.
- The graphic of the link management tool should carry a sense of simpleness and discipline (I don't like some of those messy graphics that are common these days).
- **It should prevent me from storing the same link twice (that prevents the tool from getting messy and can be a good reminder of my previous studies when I encounter the error message).**
- It's better be a single-purpose app (I don't want a crowded app).
- I don't like it to have social networking features such as following people, sharing with friends, recommending links. I want to store just my own experience on the web, not other's.
- I don't want the content of the links (especially images) be downloaded automatically (it's better be optionally) because I don't want it be crowded and of course because of my internet bills.
- The service should be stable enough to assure me that I can use it in an effective way for years.

Bolded items are more important.

Answer (score 3):

Pocket (https://getpocket.com/) is something that will meet most of those needs. It stores articles by title, allows tagging, and has cloud storage. I admit I'm not sure that it has date-based content, and it might have sharing features. It does lack a note-taking feature to my knowledge.

Evernote, paired with Evernote Web Clipper, would also be a potential option for you. This should allow the note taking you seek, but Evernote is multipurpose. It does lack social media features that I know of, though you can share notebooks with other users if you wish. You have some control of what parts of the page (i.e. images) are downloaded with the Web Clipper. Evernote does support cloud storage but has a data limit on syncs if you don't want to pay for their premium service. Tagging is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, Pocket is indeed a good app. Although I have recently replaced Pocket for [Raindrop](https://raindrop.io/) and won't be looking back. It works like a charm and will probably meet all your needs. [Raindrop](https://raindrop.io/) checks the bolded, important items off your list, and even more. Below just an overview of how many options you have for sorting the bookmarks.

[image: sort by Manual] [image: sort by Headlines]

Additionally, [Dropmark](https://www.dropmark.com/) might also help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Evernote, I use [Nimbusweb](https://nimbusweb.me/), and their web-clipper (which is  quite flexible regarding link-saving).

Nimbusweb is a commercial service, but the annual subscription is cheaper than Evernote. I prefer Nimbusweb's featureset. For example it supports Markdown for editing, which Evernote does not (or did not, I don't know).

However, the focus is on Notes and Note-taking, not Link-Management.